# Slick grid width issue by using export excel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I'm using [SlickGrid V2.2](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/releases/tag/2.2.6), grid has `forceFitColumns: false`.

While using [**jquery.slickgrid.export.excel.js**](https://github.com/ranjithprabhuk/SlickGrid-Export-to-Excel), SlickGrid auto changes to `forceFitColumns: true` dynamically. That means the grid's width is affected.

Kindly help me out to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linked libraries used to their sources, so that possible answerers have a concrete references. Reformatted text so that the question is (a bit) more obvious.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that Excel exporter, it looks good. The Github repo has been created from a copy rather than forked, so it's hard to tell how up to date it is with the 6pac repo.
I think you'll need to investigate those issues a bit more and come back with a more specific issue.